# Datepicker react make one letter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I make one letter appear on calendar instead of two for example MO I want to be M.
I have tried useWeekdaysShort that makes three letters "MON", Does somebody know how to make "M"

Comment: What kind of datepicker? Usually you must translate "short version" to be "M" instead of "MON"

Comment: This datepicker https://reactdatepicker.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can read just first character of string you get.

```
const date = datepicker.getDate();
console.log(date[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using react-datepicker library from hackerOne, just write `formatWeekDay`.

```
<Datepicker 
  formatWeekDay={(nameOfDay) => nameOfDay.substr(0, 1)} 
/>
```

Then you can see `S M T W T F S`.